# Delete specific characters from string without using (substring) function

Tags: java

For learning purpose, I need to extract the 'del' from a string without using the (substring) function 
* please note that string is not fixed it can be changed

I solved it like in the code below but I need some help for better code as my code have a lot of lines, I need a better solution please.

```
public static String delDel(String str) {
    int num = 0;
    boolean s = false;
    char[] a = new char[str.length()];
    char[] b = new char[str.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if ((str.charAt(i) == 'd')) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                a[j] = 'd';
            }
            num = i;
            s = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (s && (str.charAt(num + 1) == 'e') && (str.charAt(num + 2) == 'l')) {
        a[num] = str.charAt(num + 1);
        a[num + 1] = str.charAt(num + 2);
    }

    String t = new String(a).trim();
    System.out.println(t);

    if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("del")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            b[i] = str.charAt(i);
        }
        for(int j =1; j<str.length()-3;j++)
         {
            for (int ii = num + 3; ii < str.length(); ii++) {
            b[j] = str.charAt(ii);
            j++;
        }}
        String tt = new String(b).trim();
        return tt;
    }
    return str;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(delDel("adelrtyc"));
}
```

Comment: Having a lot of lines doesn't necessarily mean bad code, however, your formatting is off and inconsistent in some places which is, in my opinion, worse to read than some bad code logic.

Comment: this is some confusing code. Isn't `for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) { a[j] = 'd';}`(lines 8-10) the same as `a[0]='d';`?

Comment: @Nexevis yes I need to improve my skills regarding this thanks a lot man

Comment: @f1sh yes this is the same needs to be edited thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Use following code:

```
  String text = "adelrtyc";
  text = text.replaceAll("del","");
```

Comment: There is no need to wrap `del` with `(...)+` since `replaceAll` replaces *each* occurrence of specified target, also consecutive/continuous ones.

Comment: @Pshemo I did it to underline the use of a regex, however I have edited it. thank you

Comment: Since the question specifically says not to use the substring function, I can only imagine they want to solve it at a lower level, not just use a different built in function.

Comment: What is the point of using the regex `replaceAll` here over just `text.replace("del","")` since you are not using the functionality of regex anyway.  (I am asking more for an explanation of the advantage rather than trying to say you are wrong)

Comment: @Nexevis please take a look at the implementation of replace vs replaceAll in String class. Basically, both compile the pattern and call the replace method afterwards, but the replaceAll is more straightforward for this simple case.

Comment: @robingood I am aware of the implementation, but using `replace` shows intent to not use regex functionality.  So what is the advantage of using `replaceAll`, what makes it more straightforward?  This is the only case where `replace` is used, when it is just a CharSequence, so do you mean to say `replace` should never be used?

Comment: @Nexevis no, I think all solutions are equally ok, mine is just one of them. My first proposed featured a regex, I have edited it as you can see in the comment list.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways to do it.

```java
      String del = "del";
      String str = "Thisdeldelfoo";


      // method 1 (simply delete the character from the builder
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
      sb.delete(idx, idx + del.length());
      String newStr = sb.toString();
      System.out.println(newStr);

      // method 2  (note that str.replace would replace all of them).
      newStr = str.replaceFirst(del, "");
      System.out.println(newStr);
```

Comment: Doesn't the questions title say "without using (substring) function"?

Comment: Yep.  I meant to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

At Baeldung there was a nice article about Guava CharMatcher. take a look at

https://www.baeldung.com/guava-string-charmatcher?utm_source=email-newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=auto_46_guava&tl_inbound=1&tl_target_all=1&tl_period_type=3

That's pretty awesome!

Oh! I see: It's for education! No, Guava is for use :-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your real question is on how to clean up the existing code to make it more readable, and not which library can solve the problem for you in one line.

I would give the book [Refactoring](https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html) by Martin Fowler a read.

You'll learn that variable names like `int num` and `boolean s` are impossible to understand at a glance.

---

It also sounds like you want to know if your algorithm is optimal or not. It actually is buggy, so let's start there. It won't work for strings like `"ddel"`, because you are only checking the first `'d'` that you find.

**Your algorithm:**

> delDel(str)
>
> 1. Find the index `num` of the first `'d'` contained in `str`.
> 2. If it is followed by an `"el"`, continue.
> 3. Reconstruct `str`, except the characters at `num`, `num + 1`, and `num + 2`.

Step 1 and 2 here are causing the bug.

**Modified algorithm:**

> delDel(str)
>
> 1. Find the index `num` of the next `'d'` contained in `str`.
> 2. If it is followed by an `"el"`, continue, else repeat step 1.
> 3. Reconstruct `str`, except the characters at `num`, `num + 1`, and `num + 2`.

---

Some of your operations are redundant here, which is why I assume you mentioned your code having "a lot of lines." Here are some tips for reducing that:

1. You can put the check for `'e'` and `'l'` in the same loop where you check for `'d'`.
2. `String` has a method `toCharArray()` that you should investigate.
3. The logic where you create `String t` and check if it equals `"del"` can be replaced with a simple boolean flag.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is a solution with no remove-Method.

```
public class StringDel {
  private static char[] DEL_CHARS = "del".toCharArray();

  public static String delDel(String string) {
    char[] strChars = string.toCharArray();
    // strIdx moves through the input string
    int strIdx = 0;
    // delIdx moves through the "del" string
    // as long as it maches the input string
    int delIdx = 0;

    // Will build the new string
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // Start from the begining
    while( strIdx < strChars.length ) {
        // Does the char at the acutal position mach
        // the char in the delStr Position?
        if( strChars[strIdx]==DEL_CHARS[delIdx]) {
          // YES! Move on in the delStr
          delIdx++;
          strIdx++;
        } else {
          // NO! OK, append the String to the output
          // Special condition! We could have read a part of DEL_CHARS
          if( delIdx>0 ) {
            // Copy that part to the target string
            for( int i=0; i<delIdx; i++) {
              sb.append(DEL_CHARS[i]);
            }
          }
          delIdx=0;
          // AND ANOTHER SPECIAL Specialtrick
          // Maybe the current char is like the
          // first char in CHAR_DEL. Then we have
          // a fist match and need to handle it
          // the same way.
          if( strChars[strIdx]==DEL_CHARS[delIdx] ) {
            delIdx++;
          } else {
            // Otherwise we can copy the char
            // to the target string
            sb.append(strChars[strIdx]);
          }
          strIdx++;
        }
        if( delIdx==DEL_CHARS.length ) {
          delIdx = 0;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    System.out.println(delDel("deRmovededeldelFromThisdel"));
  }
}
```